# Convert python to SML

Tags: python, sml

I've trying to convert a python program into SML language but getting stuck. Here is the python program

```py
def binomialCoeff(n, k):
    result = 1
    for i in range(1, k+1):
        result = result * (n-i+1) / i
    return result
 if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(binomialCoeff(10, 50))
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? How did you convert this code?

Comment: Hi Mike, please describe what you've done to try and solve the problem yourself, and why your approach was unsatisfactory.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to get stuck very early on here because translating such a program involves a paradigm shift: You can't use mutable variables, and your main control structure is recursion rather than iteration. So rather than "think really hard while you stare at Python code", try and see how binomial coefficients are implemented in, ideally Standard ML, but if not available, in very similar programming languages like OCaml.

To get the skeleton code out of the way, you may imagine that the solution fits the form:

```
fun binomialCoeff (n, k) =
    ...

val _ = print (Int.toString (binomialCoeff (10, 50))
```

As for the algorithm itself, [Rosetta Code's OCaml solution](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Evaluate_binomial_coefficients#OCaml) ("Simple recursive version"):

```ml
open Num;;
let rec binomial n k = if n = k then Int 1 else ((binomial (n-1) k) */ Int n) // Int (n-k)
```

can be translated to Standard ML much more easily:

```
fun binomialCoeff (n, k) =
    if n = k
    then 1
    else (binomialCoeff (n-1, k) * n) div (n-k)
```

But this isn't exactly the same algorithm as your Python code uses.

And it's neither robust nor efficient. ([This one is](https://gist.github.com/Eckankar/6105621).)

So perhaps you should ask yourself what learning goal you're aiming for here. Perhaps a simpler exercise, converting `factorial` or `fibonacci` from loops to recursion is a better task.